# generate a random number less than a number

Tags: algorithm

Point me out to some algorithm(s) which can generate a random number between 1 and x and fulfills the condition that

- the randomly generated number will depend on an external value. For
  the same external value the algorithm should always generate the same
  random value.

Comment: The condition is called **seed** and most programming languages `Random` mechanism support it. Same for most pseudorandom number generator algorithm that exist.

Comment: The *from 1 to x* is simple. Most algorithms are formulated in a way that they output `[0, 1)`, so you can simply `* x + 1` to get `[1, x]`.

Comment: Random and same are contradictory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want is actually a function from the set of possible external values to the interval [1,x] that matches some properties, probably that the

If the external values are uniformally generated on an [a,b] interval, you can just operate a linear transformation of the external value v :

```
f(v) = 1 + (x-1) * (v - a) / (b-a)
```

Otherwise, you just need to apply to the external value a function that maps the possible external values to the interval [1,x]. The resulting variable probably needs to be uniform (although you don't specify it), so the function will depend on how the external value is distributed.

Comment: I only want to generate one number. Also the above algorithm is generating the same number as the seed(v). if v is 5, it generates 5. if v is 10 it generates 10